# Fail to Run Openvswitch 2.5.0

Tags: networking, sdn, openvswitch, pox, ryu

I've removed the openvswitch version I had, and I downlaoded version (2.5.0) following the same steps in this link (https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Installing-new-version-of-Open-vSwitch) and instead of (OpenVSwitch 1.10) I used (OpenVSwitch 2.5.0). The installation went smoothly without error, but when I try to run mininent and got the following error. I've tried some suggestions I found online but none of them works.

ovs-vsctl: unix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
ovs-vsctl exited with code 1
*** Error connecting to ovs-db with ovs-vsctl
Make sure that Open vSwitch is installed, that ovsdb-server is running, and that
"ovs-vsctl show" works correctly.
You may wish to try "service openvswitch-switch start".

Could you please advise me what to do ?

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: could you please provide OS and version?

Answer (score 0):

We need 2 processes for that.

- ovsdb-server
- ovs-vswitchd

These 2 will be started with following command.

```
/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts/ovs-ctl start
```

In my case, `/usr/local/share/openvswitch/scripts` is the default location for ovs-ctl scriot,
Hope that helps.